# when i upload CSV, it is display 0 error. but while import, it gives error as Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: magento-1.9, csv

When I upload CSV file it gives 0 error. After this I click on import button. It gives following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`magentostore_dbname`.`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`,
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribut), query
>   was: INSERT INTO`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
>   `(`attribute_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY
>   UPDATE`entity_id`= VALUES(`entity_id`)

[image]

Does anyone know, how to solve it?

Comment: seems like you are using Magento default import/export , best option is to go fro magmi to upload products.....

Comment: Can you post a sample of the csv? maybe with the line that does not import.

Comment: csv is work fine in 1.9.3.1. After upgrade to 1.9.3.3 CE it gives error. Single product is not upload with csv.

Comment: @ChiragParmar please update this information in question.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Just put one column in csv. I set value "**88**" to "**_media_attribute_id**"
[image]